# Question regarding the choice of axis to satisfy equilibrium conditions

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, torque, equilibrium

I have a question regarding the choice of axis needed to satisfy the equilibrium conditions of $F_y=0$ and $F_x=0$ as demonstrated in the picture below.

My question is, can we choose any axis arbitrarily as long as the assumed $x-$ and $y-$ axis are perpendicular to each other? Or is it a must that the axis must be purely and perfectly vertical and horizontal? If the former is a requirement for static equilibrium, can someone help me understand the math behind why the latter would lead to an incorrect answer.

Perhaps the wordings might not make much sense, but the picture below will do (hopefully).

Please help, thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: The x component of $F_V$ also has a contribution in the frame you've chosen.

Comment: Yes I know; I didn’t have enough space to show it, I guess if I understand the case for the y component of Fv, then I can apply it with respect to the x component

Comment: You can, and you must. Unless you do, the analysis is incorrect (and your number for the y component will be wrong).

Comment: I guess we’re standing on two different pages, can you please elaborate more on what you first meant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with choosing a non-horizontal/vertical set of axes to perform the analysis.

However, at the very least, your calculation incorrectly accounts for the contribution from $\mathbf F_\mathrm V$. In your set of axes, you need to split it into components along the new axes:
$$
\mathbf F_\mathrm V = F_{\mathrm V||} \hat{\mathbf e}_{||} +  F_{\mathrm V\perp} \hat{\mathbf e}_{\perp}.
$$
If it is essential to obtain the parallel component $F_{\mathrm V||}$ in terms of the Cartesian components $F_{\mathrm Vx}$ and $F_{\mathrm Vy}$, then it is crucial to keep in mind that *both* of these components will contribute to $F_{\mathrm V||}$, so
\begin{align}
F_{\mathrm V||}
& = \mathbf F_\mathrm V \cdot \hat{\mathbf e}_{||}
\\ & = \left( F_{\mathrm Vx} \hat{\mathbf e}_{x} +  F_{\mathrm Vy} \hat{\mathbf e}_{y}\right)\cdot \hat{\mathbf e}_{||}
\\ & =  F_{\mathrm Vx} \hat{\mathbf e}_{x}\cdot \hat{\mathbf e}_{||} +  F_{\mathrm Vy} \hat{\mathbf e}_{y}\cdot \hat{\mathbf e}_{||}
\\ & =  F_{\mathrm Vx} \cos(30°) +  F_{\mathrm Vy} \sin(30°)
\end{align}
and similarly for the $\perp$ component. This is missing from your analysis and it is the initial discrepancy that can explain any differences between your result and the book's.

Answer (score 1):

For a static analysis and two linearly independent (non-parallel) directions will sufficie for resolving force components, although things simplify usually if the directions are orthogonal.

In your case choosing a skewed coordinate system would simplify things it seems, and as long as you are consistent in your basis vectors (directions) among all quantities involved, you will get the correct result.

In addition, any arbitray point on the plane can be used to sum torques in the moment balance equations. If lucky, you can choose locations which also simplify the equations by neglecting any forces that pass through that point.

For dynamics, you have to sum torques about the center of mass, in order to apply the equations of motion.